# Getting certain values to appear in django form

Tags: python, django

[image: Image displaying issue]

The image attached displays my current problem. Math 270 and Math 280 in the picture were created by another user and not Jay, who created Jays course. However the other user is logged in currently, and not Jay. How can I get only the courses created by the logged in user, not Jay, to appear in that drop down menu?

In my views I have the following with attempts to solve the problem:

```
class CreateQuestion(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ["title", "question", 'classe']
    template_name = "attendance_test/add_test.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.instructor = self.request.user
        return super(CreateQuestion, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateQuestion, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['classe'] = Classe.objects.filter(professor=self.request.user.id)
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        return { 'classe': Classe.objects.filter(professor=self.request.user.id) }
```

My Question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    # this is where all the courses are showing up, I only want those
    # created by the "instructor" to show up, not all instructors
    classe = models.ForeignKey(Classe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def professor_classes(self):
        return Classe.objects.filter(professor=self.professor)
```

Teacher Model:

```
class Teacher(User):  
    isProfessor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    professor_courses = models.ForeignKey('Classe', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This issue would be a problem if there were say as much as 1000 classes, but an instructor only thought 4, it would not make sense to display all 1000 when 996 had nothing to do with them. For the record I asked this question before, I got an answer but I was still not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(CreateQuestion, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['classe']= Classe.objects.filter(professor=self.request.user.id)
        return form
```

you could try something like this

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to solve this problem depending on how you structure your Django application. For example, one way could be:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        professor = kwargs.pop('professor')
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['classe'].queryset = Classe.objects.filter(professor=professor)

    class Meta:
         model = Question
         fields = ('title', 'question', 'classe')

class CreateQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form = QuestionForm
    template_name = "attendance_test/add_test.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateQuestionView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['professor'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.instructor = self.request.user
        return super(CreateQuestionView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This filters classes based on the currently logged in user.

Although I think it is incorrect to inherit `Teacher` model from `User`. More performant and traditional solution would be to use aggregation in this case:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # or
    #user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Also, you have problem with your code: `initial` is an initial selected value for the form field, it's not a range of allowed values. By setting `initial` you set an initial selected value for the form field.

`context` is a dict of variables that are passed into your template. So I believe you don't need to define `get_context` in your view (or at least it doesn't need to pass list of `Classes`).

Comment: Why do we pass in a TeacherEditView?

Comment: Sorry, @BigMonkey89WithaLeg, it was my mistake. Fixed the answer.

Comment: How do you add a ModelMultipleChoiceFieldto this form class?

Comment: You can't because you have only one foreign key. If you have a field that allow multiple choices, form class will use that field automatically. Although you can override fields and widgets and labels in the form Meta class. It's all explained in great detail in the django docs on forms.